# Worklight adapter mashup error

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

We are trying to invoke one http worklight adapter from another. We have followed steps as explained in

[Advanced adapter usage and mashup](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/server-side-development/advanced-adapter-usage-mashup/)

This works fine in worklight liberty server in eclipse. However when we deploy these adapters in worklight 6.0 running on websphere, following  error is thrown:

> [8/5/15 14:51:03:322 EDT] 00000104 webapp        E
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E:
>   [Servlet Error]-[GadgetAPIServlet]: java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.addIdentitiesToResponse(AuthenticationContext.java:343)
>     at
>   com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:208)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:964)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1104)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:914)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
>     at
>   com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
>     at
>   com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
>     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)     at
>   com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)   at
>   com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
>     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)     at
>   com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1865)

Comment: Add the adapters' XML and JS.

Comment: Everything is same as given in example in the link pasted.

Comment: So you are saying you are using the sample application as-is? Okay... you need to provide then more information on your application server. "websphere" is not enough.

Comment: We got it working by adding a security test for adapter.. thanks.

Comment: Good to hear; please do not keep this question unanswered - either write an answer or remove the question. Thanks

Comment: @IdanAdar - Thanks, have added answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85330/discussion-between-sachin-thapa-and-idan-adar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding following security test to configuration fixed it.

```
<procedure name="XXXX" securityTest="wl_unprotected"/>
```

Cheers !